# Given two primes $p$ and $q$, show that there always exists an $x$ such that only one of $p+x$ and $q+x$ is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Given any two primes $p$ and $q$ with $p \neq q$, show that there always exists an $x \in \mathbb{N}$, such that **only one** of $p+x$ and $q+x$ is prime.

How do I show this?

Comment: Let $x = dq, d\geq 1$ so $q+x$ is never prime. One of $p+x$ is prime by [Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions)

Comment: @YongHaoNg This is an excellent answer to the question, please post it as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## **Elementary solution 1**

WLOG suppose that $p < q$. Let $q = p + k$ for some positive integer $k$.

Now consider $x=k$, so
$$\{p+x,q+x\} = \{q,q+k\}$$
If $q+k$ is not prime then we are done, since $q$ is prime. Otherwise we get a new set of primes
$$
\{p',q'\} = \{q,q+k\}
$$
and we can repeat the process by adding $k$.

Each time round the new $p'$ is necessarily prime, so this will only fail if we can produce $q'$ that is prime forever.

However at the $q$-th iteration this must fail since
$$
\{p+x,q+x\} = \{p+qk,q+qk\} = \{p+qk,q(1+k)\}
$$
and $q(1+k)$ is not prime.

---

## **Solution 2:**

Let $x=dq,d\geq 1$ so that $q+x$ is never prime. Then one of $p+x$ is prime by [Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions).

Comment: Dude, smooth. I owe you a drink. Thank you :)

Answer (score 6):

**Lemma:** There exist arbitrarily long chains of consecutive composite natural numbers.

**Proof:** Let $n>2$ be given.  For each $2\le k\le n$, $n!+k$ is obviously divisible by $k$.  Therefore, every natural number from $n!+2$ through $n!+n$ is composite.  Since $n$ was arbitrary, you can make consecutive composite chains as long as you like.

---

Now, we return to the problem given above.  Without loss of generality, assume $p<q$.  Consider some chain of at least $(q-p)$ consecutive composite numbers, and let $N$ be the largest prime number less than the members of that chain.

Then $p+(N-p)$ is prime and $q+(N-p)$ is composite, since $p+(N-p)=N$ which was given to be prime and $q+(N-p)=N+(q-p)$ is either in the chain of composite numbers that we considered or between N and the start of that chain.

Comment: But how do I know that there even exist $(q-p)$ consecutive composite numbers?

Comment: @DavidsKanal I added a lemma.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Oh, I see. So basically, since $N$ is prime, $p+(N-p)$ is trivially prime, and with $q+(N-p)$, you always land either in the chain (so you land on a composite number), or on a number before it, which is guaranteed to be composite as well, because if it weren't, $N$ wouldn't be the largest prime number less than the elements of the chain. Right?

Comment: @DavidsKanal That's it.